# How to hide an option in combo box in MS Access VBA

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have two forms; a register form and an update details form.

I have a drop down on my membership type which also shows an option as cancelled. I only want the cancel option to appear on the update form and want to hide it from the register form.

Register form
[image: Register form]

Update form
[image: Update form]

Form Record Source - `SELECT tblMember.*, tblPayments.CardType, tblPayments.CardNumber, tblPayments.SecurityCode, tblPayments.ExpiryDate, tblPayments.CardholderName, tblPayments.[Payment Status] FROM tblMember INNER JOIN tblPayments ON tblMember.MemberID = tblPayments.MemberID;`

Combo Box Row Source - `SELECT [tblMemberships].[MembershipType] FROM tblMemberships;`

Is there a way of doing this?

Thank you

Comment: This certainly is possible. Provide the combo box row source, and I can show you how to modify it.

Comment: Use a different query for the combobox recordsource on each form. On one form you filter out the cancel option, on the other you don't. Your form is pretty.

Comment: Form is pretty but the font is not easiest to read.

Comment: SELECT [tblMemberships].[MembershipType] FROM tblMemberships;

This is what's on my combo box row source

Comment: Generally, one form is used to enter/edit data to one table. Why are you including tblPayments in the registration RecordSource? Should be either a subform or opened independently to enter payment info.

Answer (score 1):

As already suggested in comments, apply filter criteria. Use an SQL statement in the RowSource property (of course, substitute your actual object names).

For the Register form, exclude the item:

`SELECT TypeID, MembershipType FROM tblMemberships WHERE TypeID <> AppropriateNumberHere ORDER BY MembershipType;`

For the Update form, filter the opposite:

`SELECT TypeID, MembershipType FROM tblMemberships WHERE TypeID = AppropriateNumberHere ORDER BY MembershipType;`

Comment: SELECT [tblMemberships].[MembershipType] FROM tblMemberships; This is what's on my combo box row source

How would I put it in the format you gave?

Comment: Use the query builder to construct SQL statement. I don't know the record number of the "Cancelled" record in your table. Adjust the example SQL statement as appropriate to fit your data.

Comment: How would I find the record number of the "cancelled" record?

Comment: Is tblMemberships the table for your members info? Do you have a lookup table for the membership types? You should edit your question with this info. Show the SQL statements for the form RecordSource and the combobox RowSource. Really should have a lookup table.

Comment: tblMembers is the table for members info. tblMemberships is the list of the memberships including the cancel option which is shown above in the image. `Form Record Source - SELECT tblMember.*, tblPayments.CardType, tblPayments.CardNumber, tblPayments.SecurityCode, tblPayments.ExpiryDate, tblPayments.CardholderName, tblPayments.[Payment Status] FROM tblMember INNER JOIN tblPayments ON tblMember.MemberID = tblPayments.MemberID;`

Comment: `**Combo Box Record Source** - SELECT [tblMemberships].[MembershipType] FROM tblMemberships;` I'm sorry I really do have a basic understanding of VBA Access. How would I apply the look up table to filter the cancel option on the register form

Comment: Use the Access query builder and apply the appropriate filter criteria to construct the RowSource. This is very basic Access functionality. I edited your question to show the additional info which is what you should have done. Does tblMemberships have an ID field?

Comment: Instead of repeatedly saving the long descriptive MembershipType, should just save the record ID.